# Unexpected 'from' in query string - JAva hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private boolean isAdmin;
    @Column
    private Date registrationDate;
```

Getter setters

```
  @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<User> query = currentSession.createQuery("from User", User.class);
        List<User> users = query.getResultList();
        return users;
    }
```

from User shows unexpected 'from' error on that parameter of createQuery. What is wrong with this hql? I am new to hibernate, Thanks

Comment: Show exact error, please? Plus maybe show the annotations on your User class?

Comment: The Reason is, by mentioning the User.class in the createQuery Parameters, it by default adds from user clause. You can mention where clause here or group by, but not from clause. If you check your query which is generated by hibernate, it'll add two from clauses one by hibernate, one by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import java.util.List;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
        .createCriteria(User.class)             
        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    return users;
   }
```